# What is the simplest way to distribute Google Workspace Add-ons within an organization?

Tags: google-workspace-add-ons

I often have to create small extensions for Google Workspace Apps ( Docs, Slides, Gmail etc) which I want to give some users access to. Sometimes only a selected number of users needs them, often only for a specific use case.

Those users are often not very technical experienced so I want to have a very simple setup process for them which does not include copying Appscript files from one place to another, or having a 10 step instruction.

The best solution I came up is to always create a Google Workspace Add-on (even when a simple editor script would also work) and share the AppScript Project with those user who want the Add-on. Then those users need to install it as a test deployment from the AppScript project.

This is not an ideal solution since I actually don't want to give those users access to the Appscript Project and source code.

Publishing the Add-on within the organisation would result in a better user experience since most users know how to install addons from the marketplace but since every Add-on would need a seperate gcp project this is way to much overhead for simple scripts.

Is there any better solution to this?

Comment: `Is there any better solution to this?` is a bit of an open question as what one person considers better, another might consider worse. I don't think that there is an easy solution to what you're seeking here. Aside from making one giant Add-on which contains the code for *all* your small extensions, checks the current user and only enables the sections they should have access to (this is slow and bloaty!), there isn't going to be a way of reducing the number of GCP projects you need to publish (though of course they can all still be internal)

Comment: thank you, well the goal is to easy distribute f.e. a small Add-on to some users without going through the publishing process.